# Canonisation Request: Why put a reverse proxy in front of a WSGI server?

Tags: discussion

[Why put a reverse proxy in front of a WSGI server?](https://serverfault.com/questions/536144/why-put-a-reverse-proxy-in-front-of-a-wsgi-server)

The user "that guy from over there" has requested that this be canonised (or canonicalised?).

I've no objection to doing this, but thought I'd get the opinions of others.

Discuss.

Comment: "canonized", with a "z" =]

Comment: @ChrisS Remember Tom is one of those limey bastards.

Comment: Does that guy over there know we're discussing this?

Comment: @thatguyoverthere I dunno whether that'll ping him hard enough.

Comment: How many miracles have been attributed?

Answer (score 4):

I think it's got potential, but both the question and answer need improvement first.

- The question is a little *too* specific to a particular application server. I often see this question asked in the context of many different application servers.
- The answer could be expanded significantly. As it stands, it's only a very brief (and not very explanatory) list.

Comment: Agreed. If the question is generalized ("What are some advantages of using a reverse proxy in front of a web application?") and the answer expanded with some more detail on the differences between a reverse proxy and a simple load balancing solution I think this is a good candidate, but it needs work first...

Comment: @voretaq7 if it is generalized to "what are *some* advantages", it becomes subjective, no longer a real problem and thus off-topic.

Comment: @syneticon-dj If it is not generalized it is FAR too specific for canonization. More importantly, "What are some advantages of doing X?" / "Why might I want to consider a configuration like X?" are squarely in the realm of [*Good Subjective*](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) -- asking for well-reasoned detailed responses that explain the *Why* as opposed to just "What do you like better?"